# Are the options correct of this question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, textbook-erratum

Q) An object is being pulled in the west with 50N force and in the east with 20N force. What will be the value of the net force?

A) 53.85N

B) 63.85N

C) 43.85N

D) 50.85N

I feel that none of the options are correct. Shouldn't the answer be 30N?

Comment: I think someone doesn't know what North and South are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick check to see whether the given directions are correct. I believe the intended question has one force to the north or south and the other to the east or west. If you calculate the resultant, it turns out to be

$$F = \sqrt{50^2+20^2} \approx 53.85 \ \text{N}$$

Comment: I concur.........

Comment: So, the given question is incorrect?

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic yes.